# Exporting the result of a query

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a problem with the way my program run. The situation is that I have a form where it ask for the date then when the button submit is clicked the records which has the same date will display. After that there is a button extract where if i clicked it the results will export into a CSV file.

This is my code:

```
 <html>
        <h1> TC/GC Per Sales Frequency Bracket </h1>
            <body>
            <?php   
                $df = $_POST['df'];
                $dt = $_POST['dt'];
                $db = 'mds_reports';

                if($connect = mysql_connect("172.16.8.32", "mds_reports", "password"))
                $connect = mysql_select_db($db);
                    else die ("Unable to connect".mysql_error());

                echo '<form action = "TCFrequencyBracket.php" method = "post">';
                echo '<table>';

                echo '<tr><td>Date From :</td><td><input name = "df" type = "text" /></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Date To :</td><td><input name = "dt" type = "text" /></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td><input name = "submit" type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "submit"/></td></tr>';
                echo '</table>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</form>';

                if (isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    echo '<table border = "1" cellspacing = "1">';
                    echo '<th>Restaurant Code</th>';
                    echo '<th>Restaurant Name</th>';
                    echo '<th>100 & BELOW</th>';
                    echo '<th>101-200</th>';
                    echo '<th>201-300</th>';
                    echo '<th>301-400</th>';
                    echo '<th>401-500</th>';
                    echo '<th>501-600</th>';
                    echo '<th>601-700</th>';
                    echo '<th>701-800</th>';
                    echo '<th>801-900</th>';
                    echo '<th>901-1000</th>';
                    echo '<th>1001 & ABOVE</th>';
                    echo '<th>TOTAL TC</th>';

                    $sql = "SELECT restaurant_master.code, restaurant_master.name,

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal < '100'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '100' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '200'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '200' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '300' 
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '300' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '400'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '400' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '500'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '500' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '600'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '600' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '700'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '700' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '800'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '800' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '900'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '900' AND mds_orders.GrossTotal < '1000'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(CASE WHEN mds_orders.GrossTotal >= '1000'
                                    THEN 1 END),

                                COUNT(mds_orders.GrossTotal)

                                FROM mds_orders
                                    JOIN restaurant_master
                                        ON mds_orders.RestaurantID = restaurant_master.PKID

                                WHERE mds_orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '$df' AND '$dt'
                                      AND mds_orders.StatusFKID = 2

                                GROUP BY restaurant_master.code, restaurant_master.name";
                    // echo $sql;

                    echo 'Date select from ' . $df;
                    echo ' to ' . $dt;
                    echo '<br /><br />';

                    $result = mysql_query($sql)
                              or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error());
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    print "There are $num_rows records.<br>";
                    echo '<br />';

                    while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                    print "<tr>\n";
                    foreach ($get_info as $fields)
                    print "\t<td>$fields</td>\n";
                    print "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    echo '</table>';

                echo '<form>';
                echo '<div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<table>';
                echo '<br><input name = "extract" type = "submit" id = "extract" value = "extract"/></td><td></br></br>';
                echo '<tr><td></table></td></td>';
                echo '</form>';

                    $out = '';

                    if (isset($_POST['extract'])) {
                    $out .= $_POST['extract'];
                    }

                    $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());

                    print stripslashes($out);

                    exit;


                }
            ?>
        </body>
</html>`
```

Now the error is when I try to open the program a prompt is already displayed even if the main page haven't been displayed . And also the content of the file is the code not the result.

Comment: I fail to see how a download prompt could appear. You're not forcing a download, you're not outputting any non-html mime types, you're just outputting html, period.

Comment: Besides the code not doing what you want/expect, there are a number of design & implementation issues with this code (e.g. using the outdated mysql extension, [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) vulnerabilities, using [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) when outputting HTML, mixing data access and output). Consider posting on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though what you really need is to read a good [PHP development guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question, but a few problems I see:

- I don't see any writing to a file.
- Your `$out` variable gets the value of your button, `$_POST['extract']`, which is always `extract` and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the web server set up for PHP enabling. One way of getting the page itself as the content is when the server is not set up to run PHP. Then the server does prompt to download the page instead of running/executing it.

Before trouble shooting your code, make sure that your web server can properly serve PHP scripts or files.

Next look how you have stored the given code containing file and check its extension whether .php or not.

Then check how you have included the page in your main page or how you access the page.